# Is it possible to create structure with C like string (char *) data settable only once?

Tags: c++, string, struct, char

Is it possible to create structure with C like string (char *) data settable only once?

Would something like:

```
struct raw {
 static const char * request;
};
```

What I need is structure with data that could be written in only once, and to this something shall be convertable result of string.c_str() is there any way to create such thing in C++?

Comment: I do not want to implement read/write infrastructure if possible.

Comment: Only once per what? Per struct instance or per process lifetime?

Comment: Why do you need it to be C like? *shall be convertible result of string.c_str()* what do you mean? That it should be constructible from a `const char*` or that it has to be usable as a C string?

Comment: What's wrong with a class? Make the data private and provide a public constructor...

Comment: What about `const std::string`?

Comment: Note: your `struct raw` can have its `request` member written to repeatedly.  Maybe you wanted `const char * const request;`?

Answer (score 2):

You should state what the problem to solve is, rather than the problem with your intended solution. What is it that you *really* need?

The answer to your question is actually quite simple, but I fear that the problem is deeper I your design...

```
 struct raw {
    const char * const data;
 };

 raw r = { "hi there" };
```

Or you could (should) provide a constructor. Now if you mean to initialize this with the result of a call to `c_str()` on a string, then you will surely run into trouble, as the returned pointer is only valid until the next operation that modifies the string. You could `strdup` the c string, but then you would have to manage the duplicated string...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
struct raw {
  raw(const char* request_in) { request = request_in; }
  const char* request;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with good old encapsulation? The question tag says C++, so classes and private data are allowed. In a class scenario, the private variables are writable by class methods, but not by the rest of the program. That reduces the risk of overwrite to negligible.

On the other hand, if it's superbugs and malicious influences that you want to protect against, then nothing short of manpulations with memory protection will help. On Windows, that's accomplished with VirtualAlloc()/VirtualProtect() APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Then like this:

```
struct raw {
    raw(const char* request_in):request(request_in) {}
    const char* const request;
};
```